# Difference between var ctx=new ClientContext("") and ClientContext ctx=new ClientContext("")

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I am learning sharepoint client object model these days regarding SP2013, starting with .NET managed client object model.
I have seen many examples using var ctx=new ClientContext("") and other using ClientContext ctx=new ClientContext("") for creating clientcontext object. What is the preferred way to use?
And alsp, do we need to dispose clientcontext object?

Comment: Refer this link for Dispose of objects using Client Object Model - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62901/dispose-in-client-object-model

Answer (score 2):

The name of this feature is **implicitly typed local variable**, there is no difference:

> Local variables can be declared without giving an explicit type. The
>   `var` keyword instructs the compiler to infer the type of the variable
>   from the expression on the right side of the initialization statement.

**Source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables

The disposal of ClientContext can be done automatically by Garbage Collector, don't worry:
**More Info:**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals